# try make calculatore using php function but it`s not worked

Tags: php, html, function

i am made simple calculator with out any script,but its not worked,when i click on button  ,which ever function is declared its not work properly,

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<table align="center" border="1px" bordercolor="#CC0033" bgcolor="#99CC00"> 
<tr>
<td>
Number 1:</td><td><input type="text" name="number1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

Number 2:</td><td> <input type="text" name="number2"></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td> 
Get Result:</td><td> <input type="text" name="total"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="2">
<input type="button"  value="ADD" onclick="addition()">
<input type="button"  value="SUB" onclick="subtraction()">
<input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="multiply();">
<input type="button"   value="DIV" onclick="division()">
<input type="button"  value="MOD" onclick="modulus()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Bellow is a php functions that i am crated.but ist not worked

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

//if()
    function addition(){

        $number1=$_POST['number1'];
        $number2=$_POST['number2'];
        echo $total=$number1+$number2;

    }


    function subtraction(){

        $number1=$_POST['number1'];
        $number2=$_POST['number2'];
        echo $total=$number1-$number2;


    }


    function multiply(){

        $number1=$_POST['number1'];
        $number2=$_POST['number2'];
        echo $total=$number1*$number2;
    }


    function division(){

        $number1=$_POST['number1'];
        $number2=$_POST['number2'];
        echo $total=$number1/$number2;
    }


    function modulus(){

        $number1=$_POST['number1'];
        $number2=$_POST['number2'];
        echo $total=$number1%$number2;


    }


 ?>
```

Comment: Since when PHP started supporting calling a PHP function onClick ?

Comment: `PHP` is server side not client side like `Javascript`

Comment: If you want, create JavaScript functions called `addition()` etc, and they will work. Depends on whether you want to do the calculations on the browser or the server.

Comment: Here i a java script version  http://codepad.viper-7.com/RtLYsW

Comment: @Nikunj: just so you know, it is considered poor practice on sites like StackOverflow to ask for code to be written for you. It is much better to _really_ try it yourself, and ask for new help where you get stuck. If you are having real difficulty with coding, there is no substitute for a period of sustained, self-directed study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the on-click events are not defined in JavaScript!!!
one way to get to your goal is to remove all on click and try the following buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="ADD">
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="SUB">
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="MUL">
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="DIV">
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="MOD">
```

this way when "One" of the buttons is clicked you will test the $_POST['operation'] as follows; **and let your functions return the result to the $total**

```
<?php 
$operation = isset($_POST['operation']) ? $_POST['operation'] : NULL;
switch($operation) {
    case 'ADD':
        $total = addition();
        break;

    case 'SUB':
        $total = subtraction();
        break;

    case 'MUL':
        $total = multiply();
        break;

    case 'DIV':
        $total = division();
        break;

    case 'MOD':
        $total = modulus();
        break;

    default:
        $total = '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call php functions directly from the html context. Use a `$_POST` variable like you did with `number1` and `number2` like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="mode" value="MOD">
```

And at php side:

```
if(isset($_POST['mode']) && $_POST['mode']=='MOD') modulus();
```

...or simply use javascript.

Comment: And of course the form tag should have the "action" attribute pointing to the php page

Comment: In this case How will get form submited ?

Comment: there is no need to explicitely set the action, it will just be the current url. i changed the type of the input to submit tho ;)

Comment: Gung Foo :actuary i am freshers in php so i don`t know how to write ,but i try to learn, if you don`t mind can you write any one function for me

Comment: @GungFoo: _"there is no need to explicitly set the action [in a form]"_. This is true for most browsers afaik, but the W3C HTML validator complains if it is not present, since it is a required attribute. I use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` if the script should use itself as a form target.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
You should make javascript functions.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addition()
{
    var total = parseInt($('#number1').val()) + parseInt($('#number2').val());
    $('#total').val(total);
}

function subtraction()
{
    var total = parseInt($('#number1').val()) - parseInt($('#number2').val());
    $('#total').val(total);
}

function multiply()
{
    var total = parseInt($('#number1').val()) * parseInt($('#number2').val());
    $('#total').val(total);
}

function division()
{
    var total = parseInt($('#number1').val()) / parseInt($('#number2').val());
    $('#total').val(total);
}

function modulus()
{
    var total = parseInt($('#number1').val()) % parseInt($('#number2').val());
    $('#total').val(total);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<table align="center" border="1px" bordercolor="#CC0033" bgcolor="#99CC00"> 
<tr>
<td>
Number 1:</td><td><input type="text" name="number1" id="number1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

Number 2:</td><td> <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2"></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td> 
Get Result:</td><td> <input type="text" name="total" id="total"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="2">
<input type="button"  value="ADD" onclick="addition()">
<input type="button"  value="SUB" onclick="subtraction()">
<input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="multiply();">
<input type="button"   value="DIV" onclick="division()">
<input type="button"  value="MOD" onclick="modulus()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yash you are uding script ,i dont want to use script ,i want to use php function

Answer (score 0):

You've declared functions in PHP and you're calling that function on `onclick` event which try to call javascript function.

if you want to call php function you should try

```
<input type="button" name="add" value="ADD">

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
          addition();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mohit meheta :actuary i am freshers in php so i don`t know how to write ,but i try to learn, if you don`t mind can you write any one function for me